Can I add a menu button to my Roslyn Analyzer I wrote for VS2022?
I am writing a Roslyn analyzer for visual studio 2022. I need to add a tool menu button for some extra functionality. However, I seem to not be able to link up those two projects. When I run the project and another Visual Studio window opens, I dont see the button.
My Solution structure consists of 5 projects: CodeAnalysis, CodeAnalysis.CodeFixes, CodeAnalysis.Test, CodeAnalysis.Package and CodeAnalysis.Vsix
I tried creating a new VSIX template project in this solution named CodeAnalysis.Commands. Then I added a Command item to that project. I added this projects's name to the CodeAnalysis.Vsix/source.extension.vsixmanifest as an Asset by adding the line <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="CodeAnalysis.Commands" Path="|CodeAnalysis.Commands;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
I rebuilt the project and ran it in the Visual Studio window that pops. The command does not show up.
I am not even sure whether Roslyn Analyzers are compatible to be shipped with other extension capabilities but I gotta try. Is there someone who tried the same thing before?

It just so happens that I've recently wrote my first visual studio extension myself, so I'm no expert by any means but I've done some research (most of it using AI tools) and I've got some interesting links for you - most important one is probably the VSIX cookbook. My extension is also a Roslyn code fix provider and it has a UI so perhaps my code can help you - check out Auto entity generator repository. I can explain about the structure of the project but the comment is a bit too short for that


The command does not show up.

Did you see any error messages when you run the VSIX project in in the Visual Studio Experimental Instance?
I created a demo extension in VS2022 17.11 and found command does show up. Please check the following steps.
1.Create a new VSIX template project and name CodeAnalysisCommands.Please  remove the point(".") in your project name.
2.Replace your <Asset> you added as an Asset in .vsixmanifest file with the following:
 <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />

Test result:

Docs Referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names

No, I dont see any error messages. I can also create extensions with commands and it works by itself. However, I cannot make it work together with my code analyzer. I tried removing the point in the project name but it did not work.

Sorry for misunderstanding your question. Do you mean that you write a roslyn analyzer  project(VS extension), and when you run it in a experimental Instance with your project, the  command does not show up? Could you share a Minimal,reproducible exampleto help better understand your scenario?
